# finding pattern and then finding second pattern in lines before

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
LOCUS       contig_142             11028 bp    DNA              UNK 07-JUN-2020
DEFINITION  .
ACCESSION
VERSION
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      tx-145
  ORGANISM  tx-145
            Unclassified.
COMMENT     .
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     CDS             38..1026
                     /locus_tag="tx-145_00001"
                     /transl_table=11
                     /translation="VRLPQKKQLIHTELLDGLSAKMDFSPYLAEEHNPVQSARPVPRKK
                     PYQGDVPLEALLEDIKARTKVPAYRLRVRRGKTPGLTDSKIGGLPYWDLSQPYPADEKG
                     QPMQLLAQINFGAEDMDKPFPKTGLLQFFIGLDEMFGCNFAYAPDQKNYRVVYHPEIDG
                     SVTPDKVSALGVPGLVNDYRTSPLEAELAIYAEREDSFANDRSFVFEDAFRAAVQAVMG
                     VDMGEKESYEFLDEDAYDELFESFQETDDGCMNGGHWMLGYPSFTQEDPRPEDSPFDTL
                     LLQIDSMRDEDGGNPILWGDCGVCNFFIARTDLEKLDFSQVLYNWDCC"
     CDS             1255..2219
                     /locus_tag="tx-145_00002"
                     /transl_table=11
                     /translation="MKQRIFITLLLLVLLLASCGQAAQPHAQSEPAATPSEVEKIAFTD
                     ALGQDFFIDPPQRAVVMIGSFADVWVLAGGEDVLAATANDAWESYALDLPEDTVNIGSP
                     MKPNVELVLGAQPDLIIASSLSPSNLELQETFQRAGIPAAYFDVSSFQDYLDLLELFTR
                     LTGRPENYETYGAAVKAQVDGAVDRRVEYSFAPTVLTIQVSGSSVKVKNSEDNVLGPML
                     KELGCENIADRDGSLLEDLSLEAILQADPDFIFAVYHGTDEAAARANLEESLLSNPAWA
                     SLSAVEGGRFHILERRMFSLKPNALWGDAYEQLADILCGE"
```

I would like to use grep/awk/sed to find the locus_tag `tx-145_00002`, and if found, I need to retrieve the contig ID, i.e. `contig_142` that is several lines before the first match.

Note: I have tried to use `grep -B NUMBER_of_lines`, but the number of lines between two matches is not always consistent, and highly variable from sample to sample.

Appreciate your help with this. Thank you!

Sorry about editing this late, but if possible, my expected output should be this:

```
contig_142
tx-145_00002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written and test with shown samples in GNU `awk`

```
awk -v valtofind="tx-145_00002" '
/^LOCUS/{
  id=$2
  next
}
/\/locus_tag/ && $0 ~ "\""valtofind"\"$" {
  print id,valtofind
  id=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v valtofind="tx-145_00002" '                 ##Starting awk program from here and setting variable vartofind to value which OP wants to look.
/^LOCUS/{                                         ##Checking condition if a line starts from LOCUS then do following.
  id=$2                                           ##Setting id with $2 of current line.
  next                                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/\/locus_tag/ && $0 ~ "\""valtofind"\"$" {        ##Checking condition if line has /locus_tag and variable at the end of line then do following.
  print id,valtofind                              ##Printing id and variable here.
  id=""                                           ##Nullifying id here.
}
' Input_file                                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13. It works for the most part. However, I'm also getting the contig_ID from the very last contig, even though it doesn't have `tx-145_00002`. Also, would it be possible to print the first path as well, i.e. `tx-145_00002`?

Comment: Also, the output I got from the first trial was this `contig_142 \n contig_106941`. Interestingly, `contig_106941` is the very last contig_ID in the .gbk (genbank) file. However, it does not have the `tx-145_00002` locus_tag and should not be printed. Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: @SusheelBusi,sure, edited my solution now, could you please check it. Also in variable `valtofind` mention id eg-->`tx-145_00002` which you need to search and you can change its value as per your need too, kindly do check and lemme know on it plese.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you very much! I voted for your solution, because of the ease with which I can replace the `locus_tag`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^LOCUS/h;/locus_tag.*tx-145_00002/!d;x;s/^\S+\s+(\S+).*/\1/' file
```

On a match with `LOCUS` make a copy of this line in the hold space.

On a match of `locus_tag` and `tx-145_00002`, swap to the copy and extract the id.